# How can I select an element that is not the child of a specific parent based on the parents class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example, I would like to select the two divs with data-role of content that are not children of a data-role="page" div with class "modal".  I am not well versed in advanced CSS selectors.

```
<div>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="modal">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things but I can't get anything to work... e.g.

```
[data-role="content"]:not([data-role="page"].modal > :after)
```

or

```
[data-role="content"]:not([data-role="page"].modal > [data-role="content"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[data-role="page"]:not(.modal) > [data-role="content"]
```

This gets all the elements whose `data-role` is `page` **and** who does **not** has the class `modal`, then get all their immediate children whose `data-role` is `content`.

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/txFg7/).

Comment: Thanks.  I just posted this in a comment to Kolink.  I will accept this when the time restriction is up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it with:

```
:not([data-role=page])>[data-role=content] {...}
```

But for better compatbility you might want to see if you can do:

```
[data-role=content] {/* define some styles */}
[data-role=page]>[data-role=content] {/* cancel out the previously-defined styles */}
```

Comment: that isn't really what I was after but you did give me the correct idea of '[data-role="page"]:not(.modal) > [data-role="content"]'